# Significance test for ratio

Tags: statistics

I have that a certain action is performed by $N_1$ unique users in a total of $M_1$ times in the control group, and by $N_2$ unique users in a total of $M_2$ times in the treatment group. I want to calculate if the average number of actions performed by the user $(M/N)$ has changed significantly in the treatment group, meaning if $M_2/N_2$ is significantly bigger or smaller than $M_1/N_1$. Which test/method should I use?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.